# Symfony2: How to use doctrine to select all field in database without junk data

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just realize that in symfony if you didn't not mention specific field the doctrine will return you a lot of junk data such as debug time and etc. How can we query all database field with only the field results? Example: SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'abc', then it will only return all fields in user table not including those junk data.

```
$q = $this
     ->createQueryBuilder('u')
     ->where('u.username = :username')
     ->setParameter('username', $username)
     ->getQuery();

try {
    // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
    // if there is no record matching the criteria.
    $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    var_dump($user);
} catch (NoResultException $e) {
     $user = false;
}
```

**The results of the above code:**

[image]

I don't need all those data, I only need the fields in the data. Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a junk. It's probably whole Doctrine, since your object has reference to it. Do you want to get rid of Doctrine? Doctrine has many internal mechanisms you don't usually think about, because... well... it's the ORM and not just queries and flat objects.

Only thing you get from database is data you want and doctrine don't perform useless queries.

I think you just don't fully understand how doctrine works. You in fact DO WANT that whole object. It's a point of the Doctrine - to map your database to objects. That is what "ORM" means. It's main feature, not a flaw.

---

However sometimes you do really want just plain data without all doctrine thing. You can get that. Just change hydration to array (check doctrine docs for more details about what hydration is). Use

```
$q->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

That also happen by default if you choose only some fields instead of whole object.

Comment: Thanks man, this is what I want. Sorry for being not clear in the question, the junk I mentioned here is the data I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You are using var_dump.  That is what is annotating the data.  There is nothing external in there, but you are dumping a giant object tree.  Usually it hangs, so you're lucky you even got anything there.

Use this instead for just getting the raw data:

```
Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user);
```

Comment: You are right, it hangs. I stop it half way though. But doesn't it means that the variable $user contains that much of data? I doubt it will consume more memory space compare to if I only can get those fields in the table. Because when I try to specified the fields in the select statement, I would not get those junk data.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I think you don't understand what I want. I am not just want to view the results, I want to get rid of those junk data returned from the query because I doubt it will affect the performance. Thank for you reply and help.

Comment: When you use a dump of any sort, it is going to annotate the array.  The raw data is all that is actually being returned.  This Debug::dump() is purely to insure that the data exists in the format you expect.  Use the example provided in the other answer or any of the other result oriented methods to get at specific data.  With that said, the point of doctrine is to work with objects that handle the details of their internal data for you, and make saving and changing the data close to transparent.  You're not supposed to care about the "raw" data.  Only that you have one or more objects.

Comment: Oh yeah, one thing you should try and avoid is micro-optimization or theoretical optimization.  Your assumption about the cost of this in either performance or memory can easily lead you down the rabbit hole.  You have a controller that is bringing back a single object.  You shouldn't be concerned about the object overhead until you are clear that the overhead is a problem.